# Javascript OR operator shorthand

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement an OR logic in my application. I stumbled across something like below and wondered whether we still need to write OR operation in such an expanded manner. Do we have a simpler/better way to write the same for OR operator instead of writing it like below ?

```
   (x == 5 || x == 15)
```

Comment: What does "a shorthand for OR" mean? Do you want to avoid repeating `x`?

Comment: @Oriel, exactly. If suppose i need to compare x with a series of numbers using OR operator. Is there a shortway to represent the same logic

Comment: There are languages where you can write something like `x = 5 | 15` (with the above-mentioned meaning). JavaScript isn't one of these.

Comment: You can do something like `[5,15].indexOf(x) > -1` which is only a gain if you have a larger set to test against. You lose clarity for saving a few characters.

Comment: Yeah we don't want to compromise the basics anyway

Comment: How many ORs are we talking about?

Comment: Map `x` to a set where `f(x)` is `true` for your values, `false` otherwise: `var xval = {5:true, 15:true}; if (xval[x])..`

Comment: `~[5,15].indexOf(x)` is shorter, but it's an integer instead of a bool.

Comment: @Oriol I used and liked this notation for some time, until I had someone else working with me on that code. He wasn't familiar with this notation. Since that time, I prefer readability at the expense of a few characters. Who knows how long one will be alone coding?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, albeit it will require you to pass values into an array, using up more memory to create the array. Here is how:

Instead of writing

```
    if (x == 15 || x == 5) doSomething();
```

You can write

```
    if ([5,15].indexOf(x) != -1) doSomething();
```

Comment: You can use MDN's suggested [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill) for IE8 and earlier

Comment: The second code is more complicated then the first one.